# Search Bar using leaflet, in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, search, leaflet

I am having trouble finding a solution to creating a searchbar in a leaflet map using Angular/Typescript. I want the search bar to search for names of points on the map, instaed of using a geosearch that can only search addresses.

I have tried:

leaflet-control-search, but this does not support typescript, I have tried a couple small workarounds like using https://github.com/bastisk/leaflet-search-types/blob/master/index.d.ts, and was able to get the searchbar to display on the map, but no search results will show.

leaflet-geosearch, this does work, but I was wanting to search names of points I have on the map, instead of searching the address.

I cannot seem to find any examples of using a leaflet search plugin in typescript.

Anybody have any tips to try and get this working?

```
    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
      layer: schools.eachLayer(layer => FeatureHelper.mapFeatureLayerData(PointFeatureType.SCHOOL, layer)),
      marker: false,
  });
  map.addControl(searchControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Back again...

I was able to temporarily resolve the issue by:

npm i leaflet-search

next, I added index.d.ts from https://github.com/bastisk/leaflet-search-types in my node-modules, @types, created folder 'leaflet-search' and added it there.
The downside to this is that whenever npm i is run after adding this file, it will be deleted.

I am able to search locations by name specified in my layer-feature.type.ts

This issue is not totally resolved as i cannot build the project since the index.d.ts deletes.

Comment: To prevent the folder delete, simply put your `index.d.ts` file to another folder (not in the `node_module` foder) and include in in the [`typeRoot`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) parameter of your `tsconfig.json` file.